# How to pronounce "equicontinuous"?

Tags: real-analysis, pronunciation

I couldn't find the word **equicontinuous** in the dictionary, so I hope this is the right place to ask. The definition can be found in the wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity

If I google "equicontinuous pronunciation" I can find two different pronunciations in the Youtube. The first one is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UARM56zy-gI, in which it is pronounced as we pronounce **equivalent**. There is no accent on **e**.

On the other hand, in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6Pfforz3V0, it is prounced differently, as we pronounce **equivariant** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivariant_map). There is a (second) accent on **e**. So, which one is correct?

Comment: [I'd say either is fine. Or was it either?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZ3fjQa5Hls)

Comment: That tonal difference that you are hearing at the beginning are two [phones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_(phonetics)) that belong to the same [phoneme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme) class /e/. If you happen to speak a tonal language, you have to get used to English having wider phonemes. Many dissimilar sounds are considered the equivalent. English is very flexible. You can pronounce it in any way you want. As long as your interlocutor understands you, you are pronouncing it correct. There is no absurd academy of language pretending to tell you what is right or wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simply put, the only way I have ever said it, and the only way I have ever heard it said, has been as: *eck—we-continuous*